# MySQL return a STRING instead of JSON in Sequelize 5

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, database, sequelize.js

MySQL return a STRING object instead of JSON when I made a request to the server.

Here is the model instances

```
const Task = sequelize.define(task, {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  questions: DataTypes.JSON
})

return Task
```

and the controller

```
async index(req.res) {
  try{
     const id = req.params
     const getTask = await task.findOne(
     {
       where: {id: id}
     },
     { raw: true }
     )
     
     res.send(getTask)
  }
  catch(e) {}
}
```

How to get the actual JSON data instead of STRING? Thank you

Comment: parse the data using JSON.parse() ...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not parsing your result data.

```
async index(req,res) {
  try{
     const id = req.params
     const getTask = await task.findOne({
     where: {
        id: id,
    },
     })
     console.log(getTask)
  }
  catch(e) {}
}
```

Comment: It send me an error saying: Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: I think findOne returns array

Comment: I have updated my answer. If this returns the array. You can simply assign it to a key in an object.

Comment: the JSON.parse actually work, I only need to use the method on field that I want to convert into array, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used MySql DB on the MariaDB driver! 
you can change sequelize `dialect` to MariaDB

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("myDB", "root", "myPass", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mariadb",
});
```

also you need to install mariadb package  
`npm install mariadb --save` 
or 
`yarn add mariadb --save`

it worked for me.